# console output in loops: how to completely clean last cat ouput without adding a line break?

Tags: r, loops

I often add the following to loops to print out some message for each iteration.

```
for (word in c("a", "long message", "c")) {
  cat("\r", word)
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

[image]

As we see, the message `"c"` only overwrites part of the previous `"long message"`. I would like to avoid that. The only thing I can come up with is to add extra blanks, e.g.

```
for (word in c("a", "long message", "c")) {
  cat("\r", word, "                ")
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

**Is there a better approach to get a clean message after a carriage return? Note, that I do not want linebreaks.**

UPDATE: @user1981275 posted a solution which is confirmed to work on Linux. Platform independent solutions are still wanted.

Comment: not neat but for windows, you can call `system("cmd /c cls")`. e.g. `for (word in c("a", "long message", "c")) {
    cat("\r", word);
    Sys.sleep(1L);
    system("cmd /c cls");
}`

Answer (score 3):

The ANSI *Erase to end of line* escape sequence `\033[K` can be used with `cat` (see for example [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)):

```
for (word in c("a", "long message", "c")) {
  cat("\r", "\033[K", word)
  flush.console()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: This prints nothing in my console. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Same for me on Windows. No output at all.

Comment: Works great on macOS with R 4.1. Thanks!